The VS Code source control "branches" UI disappeared
After updating to the latest version of VSCode(1.95 I believe),
The "branches" tag nologer appeared in source control panel.
(Which means you could not view/swich your local branches with that panel anymore)
Does anyone else meet the same problem?

How to recover the branches UI?

Branches, stashes, etc. now show in the GitLens panel. You can detach them so they work the way they used to by opening the ellipsis menu.


